# Is there a right way to manipulate GoogleAppEngine security permissions?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, security

I have a GoogleAppEngine application that is required to connect to another localhost server, but when I'm trying to do this from the server code, I get:

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission localhost resolve)`

I know that I can specify my additional security grant by using java virtual machine arguments (I specify them in *Web Application* run configuration):

`java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=WEB-INF/java.policy`

with `java.policy` contents:

```
grant {
       permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:8081", "connect, resolve";
};
```

but it overrides the GoogleAppEngine internal security manager which is located in private class at `com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager`, so the properties, required for AppEngine itself are disabled in that way.

Is there any way to make GoogleAppEngine internal security manager class use my policy file instead of replacing it manually with a stub (allowing anything) file in a jar?

Comment: I found a dummy class solution at  http://dmitrygusev.blogspot.com/2009/08/turn-java-security-manager-off-in.html , but I still hope to find another way to override just one permission

Comment: How do you expect to run the local server on AppEngine?  If you are going to run the server somewhere else is it going to run into some other problems?  (firewall, Google restrictions)

Comment: yes, but localhost is just a test one/substitute, I've wanted to be able to connect with another open server (jabber, for example), but yes, very possibly it will be restricted at GAE (I hoped, I have an allowed possibility to override these settings if I truly understand what I'm doing, but I see now that it is ok at localhost but not ok at GAE)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open sockets on App Engine. You need to use the [URLFetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/), either via java.net or directly. How do you expect to access 'localhost' when your app has been uploaded to App Engine, though?

Comment: ...no, sorry, my server's port is not 80/443, it's an openfire server and I use specific java library to use an application on it, and this library, in its way, uses `SocketAddress` to connect to. I will just use no GAE. Question is have no answer, seems, just 'No connections to non-80/443 allowed'.

Answer (score 0):

if you specifically need to use jabber (xmpp), you can use app engine's [XMPP API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html).