# Java GAE :: Error: "Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket connect: permission denied..

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, google-app-engine

I got Error when running application as Web Application but the same file when I'm running as a Java Application it is working fine..
Let me explain in bit more details 
Here is the code which when I'm running as a Java application it is working perfect

```
 package com.gst.user.dao.impl;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Sqldbconnect {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("-------- SQL JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your mysql jdbc Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Mysql JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://Idatabase:65535;DatabaseName=Data_Base", "DUser","DPass");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it!");
            connection.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

But almost the same thing and in the same package if I try to run as web application it throws exception..
Here is the code for that

```
package com.gst.user.dao.impl;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.gst.user.dao.CallSPDao;

public class CallSPDaoImpl implements CallSPDao {

    @Override
    public void callSPDao() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Calling Stored processor Begins");

        System.out.println("-------- SQL JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your mysql jdbc Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Mysql JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://Idatabase:65535;DatabaseName=Data_Base", "DUser","DPass");
                //  
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it!");
            connection.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }


    }
```

And the exception is ::

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host IL93SQLF031, port 65535 has failed. Error: "Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket connect: permission denied.. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1049)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.gst.user.dao.impl.CallSPDaoImpl.callSPDao(CallSPDaoImpl.java:38)
at com.gst.user.action.UnsubscribeAction.unsubscribeUser(UnsubscribeAction.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:380)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

The SQLSERVER is accepting the TCP/IP connection..
And I'm using GAE 1.7.2,JDK 1.6.0_29, building JAVA application on Windows x64.
Any Idea how to solve this issue..I think firewall is not an issue

Any help/idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your application does not have permission to open a socket connection, because of the java.policy that is used for your application. I have no experience with GAE, but I assume there are some restrictions, and this might be one of them.

See http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html
and
[Is there a right way to manipulate GoogleAppEngine security permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454519/is-there-a-right-way-to-manipulate-googleappengine-security-permissions)

Comment: :: It may be correct as I was not able to read a file,nowthe question is how do I get get rid of it.. any standard example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get in touch with an SQL Server on your local network from a Google App Engine web app?

First, does `Idatabase` or `IL93SQLF031` resolve in DNS (hint: I would expect not), and if they do, is the SQL Server exposed to the Internet directly or via NAT (hint: Again, likely not).

**Edit**: If you intend to run your application on GAE you should probably read up on the [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) .

Cheers,

Comment: Yes its my local network and I'm trying to connect SQL Server from GAE

Comment: Then you will need to expose you SQL Server to the world, probably by NAT'ing in your router or VPN/SSH tunneling. Also see my edit on the answer.

Comment: I'll be using tunneling later but for now how am I able to access it as a Java application but not as a web application?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a socket because of the Policy from Appengine. Like you may not use the filesystem, for example. Google lists all things you may not do, as well as the list of whitelisted classes and packages (out of the standard Java packages) you may use. If you try to go beyond the limits, you get this Exception.
Therefore it logically works when you run it as a Java App, because in this case your compiler does not go through the Appengine (and GWT) validations.
So for your project, just keep in Mind that an Appengine instance cannot open sockets, and therefore you cannot use your own SQL server. You have to use google cloud SQL. The only way for an appengine instance to get data from 'outside' the cloud is the URL Fetch API, wich can fetch content outside from appengine.